# For loop Issue while a data is null

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I'm building an Web App with `AsyncTask`. Using `for` loop because I have a `CustomListAdapter` for a `ListView`. The `onPostExecute()` contains below code.

```
JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(json);
 if(jarr.length() > 0){
  List<String> listImage  = new ArrayList<>();

  for(int i = 0; i<jarr.length(); i++){
    JSONObject job = new JSONArray(json).getJSONObject(i);
    if(job.getString("better_featured_image") != null){
    listImage.add(i, job.getJSONObject("better_featured_image").getJSONObject("media_details").getJSONObject("sizes").getJSONObject("medium").getString("source_url"));         
    String[] itr = listImage.toArray(new String[i]);
    image = itr.clone();
    }
  }     
}
```

The `json` response is like below. The first line is expanded for clear example and next are collapsed to understand easily.

```
[{"id":1, "title":{"rendered":" The Title"}, "better_featured_image":{" media_detais":{"sizes":{"medium":{"source_url":"http://thumbnail_url.png"}}}},

 {"id":2.....,"source_url":"url.png"},
 {"id":3.....,"source_url":"url.png"},

 {"id":4.....,"better_featured_image":null},

 {"id":5.....,"source_url":"url.png"}]
```

You can see it's `WP Rest Api` and I'm also using `Better Featured Image - WP Rest Api`.

The requested url is like below `http://..../wp-api/posts?per_page=10&fields=id,title,excerpt,better_featured_image`.

Everything this fine and I'm able to show Image on `ImageView`. Url for id 1,2,3,5 is okay following the above `json` response.

But, notice the response for `id:4`. It contains null on `better_featured_image` because this article hasn't any featured image.

My `java` code mentioned above works well but got stopped for this null value. You can see I've tried a little. But, it's failing because I've to pass the urls to `String[] image` array which will be used to load `Bitmap` with `AsyncTask` on another `Activity`.

---

So, my problem and codes are big.

The `List listImage` contains the urls which are injected with `for` loop. But, the `null` valued one is causing problem.

I want all urls should be okay and which is containing null value will add `null` string to the list.

---

What I've accepted

```
1 => 1st url
2 => 2nd url
3 => 3rd url
4 => null
5 => 5th url
```

What I get

```
1 => 1st url
2 => 2nd url
3 => 3rd url
4 => 5th url
```

---

I'm not getting idea. Because, it's very hard to do with `loop`.

How can I do that.

Comment: `My java code mentioned above works well but got stopped for this null value` ??? What do you mean exactly? Crash? Exception? Post the logcat!

Comment: `String[] itr = listImage.toArray(new String[i]);
    image = itr.clone();` ?? What sense does it make to do this inside the loop? I would expect only one call after the loop.

Comment: `if(job.getString("better_featured_image") != null)` Does that work? Is that null discovered?

Comment: @greenapps Crushes

Comment: @greenapps Yes `!=null` exclude this result from the list. Unless it throws exception here.

Comment: Please react to all i said. And if you have still a crash then post the logcat.

Comment: @greenapps Please, notice what I've updated

Comment: `Please react to all i said.`. Please do!

Comment: @greenapps 1:Yes, it crashes for this error.2:Here's no problem itr is getting response as I've accepted.3: No, it's not working.

Comment: `String[] itr = listImage.toArray(new String[i]); image = itr.clone(); ?? What sense does it make to do this inside the loop? I would expect only one call after the loop.`. Please answer and try outside loop.

Comment: @greenapps This code transform the `List` to `String[]`

Comment: My god.. I know. React to what i said! I said to take those lines out of the loop. Put them after the loop!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(job.getString("better_featured_image") == null)
     listImage.add(i, "null");
```

I wonder why you use an `i` there.

Comment: For injecting value with this loop. Why? Shouldn't I use that?